# What is the benefit of streams on network transmissions? (C#)

Tags: c#, networking, serialization, stream

I am new to programming. At the moment im writing a litle chat program to learn some stuff.

Now I am asking my self, why is everone talking about streams `(NetworkStreams)` as a solution to transmit data in C#?

On my litle tool, I transmit (and serialize) data like this:

```
    internal void sendMessageObject(Message message)
    {
        byte[] _data;

        BinaryFormatter _bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream _ms = new MemoryStream();

        _bf.Serialize(_ms, message);

        _data = _ms.ToArray();

        clientSocket.Send(_data);
    }
```

and on the receiving side like this:

```
private void readData()
    {
        byte[] buffer;

        buffer = new byte[Accepted.Available];
        Accepted.Receive(buffer);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        Message message = (Message) bf.Deserialize(ms);


        MainWindow.writeToMessages(
            String.Format("[" + message.getMessageTime() + 
            "] " + message.getNickname() + 
            ": " + message.getMessageText() + 
            Environment.NewLine));
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with it or does using Streams brings any significant advantage?

Thanks

Comment: Does the code you posted actually work?  The transport layer for Network Stream is TCP.  TCP sends datagrams with a maximum length of ~1500 bytes.  Longer messages are composed using multiple datagrams that are combined in the Network Driver.  Using a Network Stream on the receive end of a connection keeps the data in a single object instead of getting data in chunks of 1500 bytes.

Comment: Hey, yes it works, but i only tried simple very small objects of about 150 byte which would fitt in one package. do you mean it would break if a would send an object which is bigger than 1500 byte?

Comment: You code with data than 1500 bytes will attempt to deserialize with first datagram (before all the data is received).  The solution is to add a byte count at beginning of message when sending.  Then remove byte count at  receive end and read all the bytes before deserialize so you deserialize the entire message.

Comment: thank you very much, I will post the code if it is done. To answer the question. Using strams would solve the problem of multiple datagrams containing one data (object)!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wanted to summerize the given answers to a final answer:

in short:
packeges greater thatn ~1500 bytes will end in an exception on the receiving sinde, because the receiver dont know how much packets a complete segment needs.

If you send only very small packeges and you can be sure the wont be devided into more than one package, this solusion is ok! otherwise use streams!

thanks to @jdweng

bye